# Label not showing in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, labeling, attribute-table

I created a line by importing a delimited CSV file and the line appears fine. I can add a label on the line by using the `"begin"` or `"end"` attributes but not the `"Name"` attribute. It is not showing a label. So I assume the value of `"Name"` is somehow blank although I have it defined in the CSV file:

[image: csv]

I define the value as `"Name"` on the Layer Properties/Label tab:

[image]

Is there a way of looking at the attribute values after the import?

After fixing the CSV import file, I get:

[image]

I think Stu Smith is right that I was labeling the points and not the line. But how do I do that when the there is no attribute on the line style:

[image]

Comment: I see two fields having the name `Name`. The first field contains `p1` and `p2`, and the second field contains `Topic 1` and `Topic 2`. Change one of the field names to a different name, and confirm if the issue still exists.

Comment: Did you check the checkbox to show all labels?

Comment: Both are great insights! I didn't notice the duplicate Name column. I will fix that! Also where is the checkbox to show all labels?

Comment: Okay. I changed the CSV file so I don't have duplicate column names and got the labels to appear on the line but it is at the ends (probably due to my CSV having two label names). But is there a way to just have one label in the middle of the line. I used the Points to Path feature to create the line. See image in original posting.

Comment: Looks to me like you're labeling the point layer, not the line layer.

Comment: I think Stu Smith is right that I was labeling the points and not the line. But how do I do that when the there is no attribute on the line style - see image above.

Comment: Your line is beeing created from those two points. But connecting two points will result in one line. Points to Path tool takes over attributes of both points, you have selected in "Order field", naming it "begin" and "end". So "begin" contains the selected attribute from your startpoint, and "end" contains the selected attribute from your endpoint. If you want to show both, you can use an expression like `"begin" || ' - ' || "end"` in your value field.

Comment: That worked! But I really want to have a label name different than P1 or P2 - like "Pike Road" Is there any way of doing that from a CSV file? If not, how do I add an attribute to the line layer so that I can specify it?

Comment: I figured part of it out! From this: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html - open attribute table and add an attribute that you can refer to for the label and then you can display it on the line! I would still like to specify the label from within a CSV table. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @bdelliot did you find a solution to replace P1, P2,..by something else ?

Comment: Yes! See my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to label the points fine from the functionality provided but I figured it out the part about labeling a line! The trick is not to use the Points to Path plugin but simply "Add Delimited Text Layer" and then turn on the Labels from the Layers Style menu. This posting proves the first part: QGIS How to draw lines from two points in a CSV? [QGIS How to draw lines from two points in a CSV?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194302/qgis-how-to-draw-lines-from-two-points-in-a-csv?rq=1)