# Using Points to Path Plug-in of QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, path

I was able to use the Points to Path plugin to create a simple line with a label in the middle:

[image]

Here is the very simple text file I used:

ID;GEOM
"BL2990";"LINESTRING(490206.73 214102.673, 490236.94 214134.576)"

The problem is I can't recreate this again? I get the following error:

[image]

> Dependent field could not be populated.

How do I fix this error?

This might provide some clues but I can't figure it out:

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21055

Perhaps I have to create a layer first.

I like this approach because it is one file and I don't have a lot of steps like importing a text delimited file and then have to connect them and such.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! The trick is not to use the Points to Path plugin but simply "Add Delimited Text Layer" and then turn on the Labels from the Layers Style menu. This posting proves the first part: [QGIS How to draw lines from two points in a CSV?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194302/qgis-how-to-draw-lines-from-two-points-in-a-csv?rq=1)