# Make lines from points in Geometry Generator

Tags: qgis

I have a data set with a large number of start and end positions.  I am trying to generate lines between start and end positions using the Geometry Generator but it does not work.  I get no errors when running it, but the lines do not appear. I have found several answers to a similar qestion, e.g. this one, : [Creating a line from two points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247008/creating-a-line-from-two-points-in-qgis)  I select geometry Type as "LineString.   Here is the code I have been trying to use.  `make_line(make_point("shootlon" ,"shootlat"), make_point("haullon", "haullat"))`

[image]

Small screenshot of the data, which is a text ("txt") file.
  What could be the problem?   Some of the older plugins e.g. "Points2one", do not work in QGIS 3.4.4.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Are your points displayed properly?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, they are displayed well. The strange this is that the layers show the line symbol in front of the variable for few seconds but then disappears.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but the first two rows of your data work fine with your code. Check the symbology and whether your layer is visible or not.

Comment: Thanks Erik.  I also tried with the first two lines and it does not work.  In the symbology it says I have created a line but he line is not visible.

Comment: The projection of the generated unseen line layer is "EPSG:4326-WGS84",  while some other layers are in "EPSG:3395/World Mercator"

Comment: Hello @Stefán, did you change the Geometry Type to Linestring?

Comment: Hi Yannick.  Yes, using the Geometry type to Linestring /multiLineString

Comment: So, in you have as the  *Output preview : <geometry : LineString>* ?

Comment: No.  Actually I got  In the "Expression Dialog" the following "Output preview: NULL"

Comment: I have cracked the problem.    The text file from the R (using write.table) had all column names with quotation marks, e.g. "shootlat", "shootlon".  These quotation marks do not show up in the  Qgis attribute table or in the R itself (wehre I took the screenshot).  Furthermore, the script runs but with Output preview: NULL.  . So I simply removed the quotation marks and it plots the lines and now I get the Output preview <geometry:linestring   Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: Ok then, 1- Import your data (Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer), 2- Select the format or the delimiter, your X (shootlong) and Y (shootlat) fields and be sure that the preview corresponds to what you expect.
3- Load the layer, you should have your points displayed in the Layer Panel.

4. Follow the answer I suggested with screenshots below

Comment: Thanks.It works now.    I  use "quote = FALSE"  in the R write table command, i.e."  write.table(df, "C://x/x/df.txt", row.names = F, quote = FALSE) and get column headings wtithout quotation marks.

Answer (score 4):

This is how my attribute table looks like

[image]

This is the expression to use :

> make_line(make_point( "Xstart" , "Ystart" ),make_point( "Xend" , "Yend" ))

[image]

Then press Ok